# wp_remote_post() Is decoding special characters like ñ etc

Tags: wordpress, api, wordpress-rest-api

I've a problem, when using the wp_remote_post, the body is automatically converted for example from:

```
El gato negro se escondió
```

to:

```
El gato negro se escondi\u00f3
```

The response should be the first one, the problem is when receiving the response with that function, it is changing the characters all the time. It is also happening with ñ for example.

This is extremelly annoying because I need to store the data as it is! How can I disable this behaivour?

Please I need help, this is giving me crazy